# Looking for guide to select jquery lightbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have requirment to open popup window with url is jsp page , where i will have logic to search function and after search result , if select one of the result , the result value must come to parent window.

I have seen some of jquery lightbox plugins,but getting confustion to select plugin.Could you advise which plugin will fit for me.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: The lightbox plugins merely take care of the presentation of the popup window. If you want both windows to communicate, you'll have to write the code for that yourself. Lightbox plugins won't provide that functionality for you.

Comment: If both windows have the same origin, the JavaScript programs from those windows can communicate with each other directly by invoking each others objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "windows" need to communicate (i.e., you need to use javascript to manipulate the contents of the child dialog), then most likely you want to use a lightbox, not a separate "popup" window -- which is actually just a new browser window. It's much more difficult to get two separate browser windows (parent and popup) to communicate.

With a lightbox, it's usually just one browser window with a chunk of hidden html that gets displayed as an "overlay" or "modal" or "dialog". Alternatively, the chunk of html could be retrieved via ajax on demand (say, when the user clicks the link to open the lightbox) from a separate html document. Most good lightbox plugins would have this feature.

There are so many lightbox plugins, it's hard to know which one to choose. You want to make sure you go with one that's actively developed, so that you can upgrade easily at a later time. Browsers and devices are changing quickly, and you want to make sure your plugin is keeping up with the times.

Fancybox, Light Box 2, and Colorbox are quite popular these days.

If you're concerned about responsive design, check out Magnific or Flare or JackBox.

JQuery Tools has a high quality lightbox.

If you need to be able to customize the window and develop more complex logic around how and when it's displayed, jQueryUI Dialog is rock solid. It has fewer frills than other plugins and is probably a higher learning curve, but it's more flexible and configurable than most options.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ :) Really nice and customizable free plugin. Responsive, light and gives you a lot of power. For the communication window/iframe ( supposing you iFrame is from the same website ) you need to use   window.postMessage ( [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.postMessage)  )